# Temporary failure in name resolution continuously

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, dns, display-resolution

OS: Ubuntu 20.04
Hypervisor: VirtualBox
Connectivity: wired ethernet connection
[this is the result of "netplan & resolve.conf"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7aTZ.jpg)
[and this is for "IP a show"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/II8U8.jpg)

I'm getting this error continuously, only rebooting the system resolves the problem but I don't want to reboot the sys every time, so how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend that you amend the netplan file to:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.40/24
      nameservers:
        addresses: [8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 192.168.1.1
```

Follow with:

```
sudo netplan generate
sudo netplan apply
```

Next, do:

```
cd
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf 
sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

Is there any improvement?

Comment: yes, thank you the problem solved